# CSS adding background image doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with adding a background to my html site. I searched the web before posting here, but i don't see what I am doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <html lang="de">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
        <title>hi</title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <!--Text-->

        <p>
            hi
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin-top:0px;
  background: url('bg.jpg');
}
```

I made sure that the image is in the same folder as the CSS file and has the right name. But the image doesn't show up.

Comment: Maybe because your body has nearly no content you just don't see it? What are the dev-tools saying?

Comment: @Tim — Backgrounds on the body element are special cased to cover the viewport

Comment: I copy / pasted your code and added an image called bg.jpg. Whatever the problem is, it isn't exposed by anything you've said in the question.

Comment: @Tim Firebug says Url could not be loaded

Comment: @Quentin so this code works for you?

Comment: @battler11 — Yes, that code works fine.

Comment: @battler11 — Then the URL was wrong so the statement "image is in the same folder as the CSS file and has the right name" is incorrect (assuming that is the URL that the error message refers to)

Comment: @battler11 try to use `/bg.jpg` as a path. Maybe you have a problem with relative paths or something. Where is your site hosted?

Comment: Your Code works fine I have copy paste the same and it is okay .Check your url address if the path is correct or not .

Comment: @AsifuzzamanRedoy somoene deleted his answer, where i stated as comment that the code works now. i just had to restart my browser.

Answer (score -2):

```
background-image : url(../image-path);
```

Use this for get a background image

Comment: You don't need to use background-image. background is a shorthand property.